# How to define specific sheet - .getsheetbyname error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am just wanting to define a specific sheet to this code:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() == 3 && r.getValue() == '3')
    var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
    nextCell.setValue("1");  
}
```

I have tried `.getSheetByName()`:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() == 3 && r.getValue() == '3')
    var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
    nextCell.setValue("1");
}
```

But it is still working across all sheets. I have a feeling it is to do with `.getActiveCell()`, `.getColumn()` and `.getValue()`. Do I need to specify which sheet these are in too? If so, how? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use the event object. Or at least check that the name of the active sheet is a name you expect

Answer (score 0):

Use the event object to check if current sheet is the one you're trying to work on. Change `'required sheet name'` to something you need.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var name = range.getSheet().getName();
  // check if 'name' is OK
  // if OK, proceed
  // if NOT OK, return
  if (name != 'required sheet name') return;
  if (range.getColumn() == 3 && range.getValue() == '3') {
    var nextCell = range.offset(0, 1);
    nextCell.setValue('1');
  }
}
```